# How to Active Navbar When Click The Bar And Change Icon Color

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change background colour and icon color when i click the bar (active bar). Or if cant change icon color, i want to change icon with another color. This is my code and didnt change.

I'm not using class 'active', i'm using class 'clicks'.

I'm using Codeigniter and Bootstrap for Framework PHP.

This is My CSS

```
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.navbar-page a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.navbar-page a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-page img {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}

.icons {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over
.active, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
 */

/* Style the active class */
.active {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: black;
}

.clicks {
  background-color: #5A5D5A;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

#nav li.clicks a {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is My Navbar Code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('ul li a').click(function(){
        $('li a').removeClass("clicks");
        $(this).addClass("clicks");
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">   
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link clicks" href="<?php echo site_url('') ?>"><img class="iconics" src=".\assets\img\icon\home-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('product') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\product-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('feed') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\feed-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('confirm') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\payment-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('contact') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\contact-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you don't want the page to redirect and js will add the class, if the page loads via ajax or something like that. event.preventDefault() will prevent it.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('ul li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('li a').removeClass("clicks");
        $(this).addClass("clicks");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If your page redirects after clicking then, you can use the php function to add class

```
<?php 
$current_url = current_url();
?>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">   
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a  class="nav-link <?=(site_url('/')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>"><img class="iconics" src=".\assets\img\icon\home-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('product')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('product') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\product-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link onclicks <?=(site_url('feed')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('feed') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\feed-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('confirm')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('confirm') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\payment-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('contact')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('contact') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\contact-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For the page when click the bar is redirect to page on click. And for this i choose the bottom choice?

Comment: @GloriaMahena yes

Comment: Also, i would suggest try initialising your jquery with jQuery instead of $, check i have updated my code.

Comment: Okay, i will try broooo :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working, kind of... :) Try setting this style to your css.

a {height: 30px;display: block;} And remove 100% height from the .clicks class.

You will see that height of anchor not visible and that was the problem.
Can you post some screenshot in order to know is there any visibility issue?

Comment: no, when i added manually the clicks class its changes. for my codes the javascripts is not functionally :(

Comment: Well i tested it without php just plain html and css and it works fine, try to inspect css through Chrome inspect and find if any element overlaps anchor tags or if there is some "pointer-events: none" placed on anchor or parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it's removing then instantly adding the class again? Try using an if statement to check if it has it already or not etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul li a").click(function () {
          if ($( "li a" ).hasClass("clicks")) {
                $("li a").removeClass("clicks")
          } else {
               $("li a").add("clicks")
          }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your jquery code its working, i dont know your code details, maybe whitespace inside the a element, that does the problem.

try add:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

or in your case

```
.nav-link {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

check it: https://jsfiddle.net/nwoxasf6/1/

Comment: Thanks bro, tapi gue heran masi gabisa di gue faktor css dari bootstrap nya kayanya

Comment: @GloriaMahena oalah pake bootstrap pasti ketimpa sama classnya bootstrap, kenapa ngga coba pake fontawesome atau glyphicons?